# What is the difference between the following 2 lines of R code:

Tags: r, plot

```
x<- c(4,5,6,2,3,8,4,7)
y<- c(6,9,2,1,2,5,6,3)
plot(x,y)

plot(x~y)
```

What is the difference between the 2 plot functions arguments?

Answer (score 8):

`plot(x,y)`: `x` is used as x values and `y` is used as y values.

`plot(x~y)`: `y` is used as x values and `x` is used as y values.

Read the help pages: `?plot` and `?plot.formula`.

Comment: Can the downvoter please give a reason for their vote? I strive to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: My guess is maybe they thought you should have said "used for the y-axis values"... "used for the y values" could be arbitrarily assigned.  Or perhaps abscissa and ordinate?  It's a crappy downvote.

Comment: @Roland +1 haha SO should ask for a brief reason with every downvote

Answer (score 6):

If you type the letters `plot`, you see a function definition whose core is `UseMethod("plot")`. `plot` is a "generic" function, meaning the class of arguments determines how the call is dispatched.  So R will examine the class of its first argument, `x` (a numeric vector) in the case of `plot(x,y)` and `x~y` (a formula) in the case of `plot(x~y)`. Two different functions get called: `plot.default` in the first instance and `plot.formula` in the second. `plot.formula` then looks at the left-hand side (LHS) argument, "x" in this case, to further determine what method to use.

Formulas in R can generally be read as "LHS is dependent on RHS" or "LHS is distributed as RHS", so `x` in the parent.frame of the plot function would be plotted to the ordinate (commonly called the "y-axis") while y would be on the abscissa (the x-axis). See:

```
help(plot.formula)
```

Comment: What is the use of having two different (but very similar) plot functions? Confusing to new R learners.

Comment: Ha, Ha, Ha. There are not just two plotting functions. There might be hundreds of plotting functions. There are three plotting paradigms and within each paradigm, there could be as many plotting functions as there are classes of objects. Type this at your console prompt: `methods(plot)`

Comment: I just followed my own advice. I have a fairly large number of packages loaded and I have 127 plot methods available.

Answer (score 2):

In this case

```
plot(x~y)  = plot(y,x)
```

that 's why you don't have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`plot(x~y)` is a formula, and `plot(x,y)` is setting the discrete values for your axes...

Comment: Yes. Thank you. But what is the difference in the resulting graphs?

Comment: Your axes are swapped on one and the other is as you'd expect.

Comment: @Selvam have you even tried doing this? Have you looked at the graphs?  You'd get the answer.

Comment: Yes sir, I did. It is a scatterplot. What I am trying to understand is what is the graph graphed with plot(y~x) is telling me, that is different from plot(x,y).

Comment: Further, you can add to the question, plot(x~y).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hd1 for the answer. It really help me understand the difference between `~` and `,`, when ploting.

@selvam, the straightforward difference is that you are swapping axes. But perhaps this might help understand what the explanation given by @hd1 implies.

Try this:

`boxplot(y~x)` which is different from `boxplot(x~y)`

`boxplot(y,x)` interchanging the order to `boxplot(x,y)` will change the indexing in the plot.

Thanks